# React Re-Render State Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render

Wondering if anyone can help me. I am running into this weird issue when a state updates to re-renders all states in a react file:

Here is the main state that I don't want to update when doing something else:

`{dashboard.layout.map((layout, i) => createContent(layout, i))}`

However, when using Material UI Dialog I click on a button to open it which updates the state as follows:

```
onClick={handleDashletSelectorOpen}
const handleDashletSelectorOpen = () => {
    setDashletSelectorOpen(true);
  };
```

Here are the two states in question:

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState({
    layout: [],
    widgets: []
  });
const [dashletSelector, setDashletSelectorOpen] = useState(false);
```

What I would like to do is open the dialog box but without re-rendering the dashboard state. Is this possible? I'm sure there's something easy I'm missing but cannot figure it out.

Any assistance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Check that you use exact same <element key={}></element> on rendering layout, otherwise it will rerender on each function run

Comment: Yes, they should be the same as the element keys are picked up as part of the array and the array is generated from the dashboard state which doesn't change when trying to load the MUI dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this all wrong. The issue here is the different "states" aren't different states rather one state with multiple props. Once I realised this the solution was easy, to get around this I moved all of the other props that didn't matter to a child component that way if the parent re-rendered then that's fine but if the child re-renders then the parent doesn't. Worked a charm